# How to set relative paths in VS2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I've just found some source on the web and want to compile it. When I open the project and look for the relative paths of the files it writes 
**$(ZLibSrcDir)\adler32.c** 
where do I set the ZLibSrcDir at Visual Studio 2010? For somehow it is trying to look at some wrong path.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set user macros in the Property Manager. Right click a property sheet and open the properties dialog, and there's a section called User Macros. There might already be a macro called ZLibSrcDir, or you might have to create a new property sheet to be able to add it.

Answer (score 1):

You can create an environment variable called ZLibSrcDir, direct it to the correct directory, restart Visual Studio and you're ready to go.